# Analytic Geometry - vectors and points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Can somebody help me?

In the picture, $\|AM\|=2\|MB\|$ and $\|AN\|=\frac{1}{3}\|CN\|$. Write $X$ in function of $A, AB, AC$.

[image]

Comment: There is the same question and an answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728383/vector-triangle-lines-intersection-proof

Comment: @RicardoCruz thanks!!